# OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener callback is never executed

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I've my main activity that starts a new activity (`SearchResultsActivity`).
I also have a settings menu.

I want my `SearchResultsActivity` to be notified every time there is a new/edited setting from the settings menu.

I'm implementing the `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` the interface on `SearchResultsActivity` and registering itself to listen to any modification in the settings but for some odd reason the callback is never executed.

Here's my `SearchResultsActivity` code

```
public class SearchResultsActivity extends BaseActivity implements SearchResultsFragment.RouteResultsFragmentCommunicator, SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    private static final String TAG = SearchResultsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    private SearchResultsFragment mSearchResultsFragment;
    private RouteFragment mRouteFragment;
    private SharedPreferences pref;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_results);

        // Set the toolbar
        activateToolbarWithHomeEnabled();

        pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

        // Initialize the FragmentManager
        mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        mSearchResultsFragment = (SearchResultsFragment) mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.searchRouteResultsFragment);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        pref.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);

        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        pref.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSharedPreferenceChanged callback");
    }

}
```

For sake of simplicity I've removed parts of the code that has nothing to do with my issue.

So my problem is, "onSharedPreferenceChanged callback" is never printed on the logcat when I make a change on any setting.

Just in case, here's my settings implementation:

```
public class MySettings extends BaseActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MySettings.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pref_with_actionbar);

        // Set the toolbar
        activateToolbarWithHomeEnabled();

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id==android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

And the fragment:

```
public class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    private static final String TAG = MyPreferenceFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private EditTextPreference mMaxRadius;
    private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    private CheckBoxPreference mCheckBoxPreference;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        mMaxRadius = (EditTextPreference) findPreference(getResources().getString(R.string.pref_radius_key));

        mSharedPreferences = getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences();
        String maxRadius = mSharedPreferences.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.pref_radius_key), "Unknown");
        mMaxRadius.setSummary("Max Radius: " + maxRadius);

        mCheckBoxPreference = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_order_list_key));
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        if (key.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.pref_radius_key))) {
            Preference connectionPref = findPreference(key);
            // Set summary to be the user-description for the selected value
            connectionPref.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(key, "Unknown") + " km");
        }
        else if (key.equalsIgnoreCase(getString(R.string.pref_order_list_key))) {
            Preference orderByPreference = findPreference(key);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }
}
```

Please note that on `MyPreferenceFragment` the `onSharedPreferenceChanged` is called as expected, eveytime there is a settings change the `MyPreferenceFragment#onSharedPreferenceChanged` is executed. But `SearchResultsActivity#onSharedPreferenceChanged` is never called.

Can someone explain me what is wrong with `SearchResultsActivity#onSharedPreferenceChanged` never being executed when I change something on the settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register your listener in `onCreate()` and unregister in `onDestroy()`. When you start the preference activity your main activity is paused, and unregisters.

Comment: Oh, such a silly mistake from me. I guess it's time for a break. Thanks for your help and time.